# Loading NSBundle in iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store

Will my app be rejected while AppStore submission because of downloading bundles?

Downloaded bundle DOES NOT contain executable code (nib and text files only).

Comment: there is no issue if you downloading bundles

Comment: @PinkeshGjr even with executables?

Comment: Apple has done everything technically feasible to make this an impossible task - its why iOS is considered "sandboxed". If you figure out how to do it you can become rich by selling the technique (until Apple closes that hole).